# Recovering a ZFS pool after accidentally formatting a disk

Tags: zfs

I have a RAIDZ-1 pool with 5 disks on an Armbian (Buster) system.

Due to a bizarre glitch involving `armbian-config` over a faulty serial connection, one of the disks (`sda`) was repartitioned before the pool was imported on a fresh install.

Once the pool was imported, ZFS correctly noticed that something was off:

```bsh
$ sudo zpool status
  pool: pool01
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
    attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
    using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
...
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    pool01      ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     1
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

However, I'm somewhat new to ZFS and am not sure of the best way to remedy this particular situation.

My first thought (from the `action` message) was to "replace" the device so that ZFS would simply repartition the disk and resilver the data from scratch. However, it doesn't seem like I can replace a device with itself:

```bsh
$ sudo zpool replace pool01 sda
/dev/sda is in use and contains a unknown filesystem.
```

Is a `zpool scrub` sufficient here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zpool scrub pool01
```

Should be enough to check the checksums and recover them in correct block in the pool

Comment: Wow, that was too easy. A second `zpool scrub` came back clean, so I guess we're good. Thanks!